# How to detect that browser password is set?

Tags: javascript, browser, authentication, passwords

I have a login mask with a username inputfield, a password inputfield and a submit button. When the password and the username field is empty, I want the button to display the text "Guest access" otherwise "Login".

That works very well but until I save my password in the browser, the username and password fields will be filled but the button still shows "Guest access".

I already saw that instruction but it does not work for my problem:

[How to detect when browser places saved password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197539/how-to-detect-when-browser-places-saved-password)

When I click into my window or do anything else the button text changes to "Login". But not initally.

I also tried to fire an click or other event, which did not help.
I also tried to read the content of the username field with `document.getElementById('username').value` but its always emtpy, even if I can see the content.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: For security reasons, althought you see the password field filled it is really not filled after user interaction (a click for example).

Comment: So, I will have no chance to know that the browser password and username is used?

Comment: As far as I know, chrome has that behaviour. So in Chrome you cann't know if the password is autocompleted.