# Detect if login credentials are saved at the browser within a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome extension auto log a website (by submitting its login form), only in case the user has his login credentials saved at the browser.

And because the login credentials (email/password) are populated to the form after the web page loads, I'm using a JavaScript `interval` after the page load, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197539/)

So, my code as follows:

```
//use 10 seconds interval waiting for the form to populate by the saved credentials:
var waitSeconds = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {

var inputEmail = document.getElementById('email');
var inputPass = document.getElementById('password');

console.log(
        'inputEmail:', inputEmail, '\n',
        'inputPass:', inputPass, '\n',
        'inputEmail.value:', inputEmail.value, '\n',
        'inputPass.value:', inputPass.value, '\n',
        'inputEmail.defaultValue:', inputEmail.defaultValue, '\n',
        'inputPass.defaultValue:', inputPass.defaultValue, '\n',
        );

    if (inputPass.defaultValue || inputPass.value) {
        console.log('login credentials are saved at the browser!');
        clearInterval(interval);
        //click the form submit button here;

    } else {
        console.log('waiting...');
        if (waitSeconds < 10) {
            waitSeconds++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log('10 seconds passed, timeout!');
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

I get at the `console` the following:

```
inputEmail: <input autocomplete="email" type="email" id="email" value="myemail@example.com">
inputPass: <input autocomplete="password" type="password" id="password" value="myPasswordIsVisibleHere">
```

But for `inputEmail.value`, `inputPass.value`, `inputEmail.defaultValue`, `inputPass.defaultValue`, Sometimes, I get the data and sometimes I get nothing! just empty values!

I can't know what makes this happens sometimes and sometimes not, but, based on some observations, I noticed that whenever I do a manual interaction with the page it always populate the values at the console!

Manual human interaction can by something like (clicking anywhere at the page, manually focus an input, clicking F12 to open the dev tools, during the 10 seconds `interval`, etc)

Is this manual interaction a requirement by Chrome as a security measurement to prevent stealing saved users credentials? I don't know!

I tried to simulate human interaction programmatically, things like:

```
$(inputEmail).keydown().keypress().keyup().blur().focus();
```

Also thought about using `document.execCommand('paste')`, to paste a space or something after the value, out of a desperation approach!

What can I do ALWAYS get the credentials and have a consistent login functionality?

Is there a better approach I should use instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you should just store and retrieve the email and password in [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage).

If I understand correctly, the page still will not auto login until the extension button is atleast clicked once to kick off any scripts.  If that is the case, have the popup.js perform the launching & auto-login of the pages using window.open, eg.